# D3 Zoom functionality is not working in Google chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js, data-visualization

i am working on svg project  i use d3.js for better ui  , in my chart adding zoom functionality  but strange it's zoom is not working in Google chrome

```
svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

and also i want to prevent translate on node drag because node and pane both dragiing at same time so it's looks very ugly.
here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/nt3z5/)

for test drag left element to right div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically there. To get the zoom behaviour to work, transform a `g` element directly underneath the `svg` instead of the `svg` itself -- that has no effect. To prevent dragging of the nodes on SVG drag, you can use the `nodedrag` variable you've set up already -- just set it to `true` on `dragstart` and `false` on `dragend`.

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3z5/5/).

Answer (score 1):

i know this specific question has been answered, but as this is still the top question on google i would like to add another answer for the more recent 'feature' introduced by update 73 of Google Chrome which broke zoom for me (and i lost 4 hours migrating from v5 to v6 and debugging why is zoom not working)
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/scrolling-intervention

the fix for me was to add this line :

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", ()=> {passive: false});
```